# Django ORM: many_to_many.extend(some_queryset)

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

I read the docs for [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add).

I could not find a way to extend a many-to-many relation.

Example (this is what my "dream" looks like):

```
my_user.groups.extend(my_group_queryset)
```

I know that I could use this:

```
for group in my_group_queryset:
    my_user.groups.add(group)
```

But I prefer looping in DB to looping in my code ([guidelines](https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines/blob/master/README.rst#loop-in-db-not-in-your-code)).

Is there a way to add several objects to a many-to-many relation in one method call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add items in bulk, by *unpacking* the queryset, and then thus add all these elements in a single [**`.add(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) call:

```
my_user.groups.add(*my_group_queryset)
```

Notice the asterisk (`*`) in the front. This will thus unpack the queryset, and pass each item as an individual parameter to the `.add(…)` function.

Comment: I am curious: Does this execute one or N sql-statements? With other words: is the loop in the django-orm or in the DB?

Comment: @guettli: it will add items in *bulk*. That means that usually it will result in two queries: one to retrieve the items, the other to add all the items. If the number of items is *huge*, it might takea few add queries (each adding a large amount of relations).